# Backslashes in csv files

Tags: php, csv

I'm using php to read a csv file with tab as delimiter. I got a problem if the file contains backslashes. If I use the function stripslashes it works but I want to keep the values how they are in the csv file.

I think this issue is very strange.
Anyone has an idea why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: when you say "got a problem" .. what exactly does that mean?

Comment: Backslashes are considered to be *escape characters* because they give special meaning to the following character. eg \t means a TAB

Comment: How about a short example of your code, a small example CSV file, the expected result and the actual result?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code I can't give you any specific answers.  However, from personal experience, when working with CSV files I've had the best luck using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).